# How to execute exe on Azure portal

Tags: azure, scheduled-tasks

I have created one console application which is uploading files from local folder to data lake store. 
Now I want to execute its exe on Azure portal.
This exe should execute after some time intervals, like every 1 hour.
Is it possible in portal Azure by using Azure scheduler or anything else.
Actually I am new in Azure and data lake so please guide me in steps to achieve it.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking. You cannot just have the portal execute an exe. You need to deploy your code to something (virtual machine, web app, function, etc). And console app running in Azure won't be able to upload content from your local machine (unless you devise some way of initiating the upload from your machine, like a browser does, or come up with some other scheme). I'd suggest starting with the Azure site itself and reading up on ways to deploy your code. Lots and lots of how-to's there.

Comment: HI David, Sorry i missed to explain about my local folder. Actually i need to upload files from some shared location  which could be accessible from my exe. So main question is how can i execute exe after some time of intervals?

Comment: ``how can i execute exe after some time of intervals?`` Have you checked my reply? Does it meet your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

As David Makogon said, you need to choose an appropriate service/feature to run your console application on a schedule. You could know [Azure WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs), [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview), [Azure Cloud Service Worker Role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-choose-me) or Azure VM first, and then choose a service/feature for your requirements/scenarios to run your program.

> I have created one console application which is uploading files from local folder to data lake store.

If possible, you could try to store/upload the files to Azure Storage, and then you could run your program in Azure WebJobs or Azure Functions, and access the files that stored in Azure Storage and ingest files/data into Data Lake Store.

If you want to run the program in Azure Cloud Service Worker Role or Azure VM, you could also store your files/data in [Azure File storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files), and then you could mount and access the File storage share in the cloud.

Besides, as David Makogon recommended, please read Azure documentation to know these services or features, which will show you the basic usage and scenarios for.