# Deploy .NET app to Azure without building it

Tags: .net, azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I have a .NET Framework app, which is built with a special script that converts it to a .NET Core project and puts output files (.DLLs) to a specific directory.

My task is to deploy this folder to an Azure Web App Service.

- I can't build the project on Azure automatically (because the build process is specific)
- I can't send the folder as a .zip (because .zip is not cross-platform. I am archiving on Windows, but my Azure App is on Linux, so there are misunderstandings with path slashes)
- I can't send the folder as a .tar, because it's not automatically unarchived, and there is no startup script for a .NET Application in Azure, that can unarchive it.

Is there anything I can do in this case to just put the files and run a specific .exe file on Azure? Thanks.

Comment: Please refer [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802997/how-to-execute-exe-on-azure-portal)

Comment: How about using FTP?